# Problem requesting a HTTPS with TCL

Tags: https, tcl

I'm trying to do the following request using TCL (OpenACS)

```
http::register https 443 tls::socket

set url "https://encrypted.google.com"

set token [http::geturl $url -timeout 30000]

set status [http::status $token]
set answer [http::data $token]

http::cleanup $token
http::unregister https
```

The problem is that when I read the $status variable I get "eof" and the $answer variable becomes empty. I tried enabling tls V.1

```
http::register https 443 [list tls::socket -tls1 1]
```

and it works only for the site https://www.galileo.edu, but not for https://encrypted.google.com.

The site what I'm trying to connect is https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=...
but it doesn't work.

I used curl to retrieve the contents of the pages in HTTPS and it works, I have installed OpenSSL, so I can't see the problem, there is another way to do HTTPS connections with TCL?.

I can't see if this is a problem of coding (maybe I'm registered wrong the https protocol) or maybe It is a bad configuration of my server. Hope somebody helps!! Thanks!

Comment: I tested the code in other servers and it works well, so I think that is a bad configuration of the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, I can't reproduce that. Which patchlevel of Tcl are you using, and which version of the tls package?

I did this:

```
package require http
package require tls

# This is your code, cut-n-pasted with blank lines removed
http::register https 443 tls::socket
set url "https://encrypted.google.com"
set token [http::geturl $url -timeout 30000]
set status [http::status $token]
set answer [http::data $token]
http::cleanup $token
http::unregister https

puts $status
```

And it produces “`ok`” as output, with `$status`'s contents looking likely too (but too long to paste here). This is with Tcl 8.5.2 (I know I need to upgrade), http 2.7 and tls 1.6.

Comment: My version of TCL is 8.5.6, http 2.7 but the tls is 1.5 I guess I need to upgrade the tls package, thanks for your help!!!